# UrlFetchApp.fetch Link Length Limit

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having some trouble with the UrlFetchApp class, fetch() method. I've singled out the issue, and it seems to be the fact that the actual link I'm fetching is just too long

When I eliminate some needed data(resulting in ~1900 characters), it send the fetch request fine

The length limit is somewhere between 2040 and 2060 characters, as that is where it stops working and I receive a "Bad request" error. I'm assuming it's 2048, as that seems to have been the industry standard some time ago.

I'm needing to fetch data from a link that's upwards of 3400 characters! Is this just too long? 2048 characters might have been understandable a while back, but in this day in age it's a limit that is going to be met quite often

My question is this: Is there a way around this? I'm assuming Google set the limit, is there some way to request this limit be raised?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [restriction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) is on the size (2kB) and not on the length of the url.

On March 30, 2018, Google deprecated the URL Shortener service that was used in the accepted answer.

I wrote a [script](https://github.com/amitwilson/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/LinkShortner) to use the Firebase Dynamic Links Short Links API service.

The docs are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) if you want to cook your own.

Answer (score 1):

I used the POST method with payload data instead, showed here:

- [Google Apps Script POST request UrlFetchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367076/google-apps-script-post-request-urlfetchapp)

The [classic code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) is:

```
// Make a POST request with form data.
var resumeBlob = Utilities.newBlob('Hire me!', 'text/plain', 'resume.txt');
var formData = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'email': 'bob@example.com',
  'resume': resumeBlob
};
// Because payload is a JavaScript object, it is interpreted as
// as form data. (No need to specify contentType; it automatically
// defaults to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
// or 'multipart/form-data')
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [UrlShortener](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlshortener) to shorten the URL and then use UrlFetchApp with the shortened URL

Comment: Ah! Didn't even think of that. While being able to do what I need with fetch itself would be great, this is definitely a viable alternative.

Comment: Darn. Just got around to testing it and it doesn't seem to work. The shortener seems to have the same 2048 character limit. Bummer :(