# CURL XHR Google App Script - I cannot figure it out

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, xmlhttprequest

I tried for hours now, can someone just deliver me from the pain and rewrite this, so it works with Google App Script?

The requests below are working in my windows CMD and in plain Javascript. But I need it on Google App Script.

```
curl -X POST https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\",\"id\":\"dontcare\",\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\": [{\"from\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"data\":\"0x7b84daec00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280000000000000000000000009fd15feb6f86d2da6a3ac17372debd1db4e02e93\",\"to\":\"0xbda1f897e851c7ef22cd490d2cf2dace4645a904\"},\"latest\"]}"
```

```
var url = "https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0","id":"dontcare","method":"eth_call","params": [{"from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","data":"0x7b84daec00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280000000000000000000000009fd15feb6f86d2da6a3ac17372debd1db4e02e93","to":"0xbda1f897e851c7ef22cd490d2cf2dace4645a904"},"latest"]}';

xhr.send(data);
```

I got this far:

```
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
      "sec-gpc": "1"
    },
    "referrer": "https://polygonscan.com/",
    "referrerPolicy": "origin-when-cross-origin",
    "body": "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":2,\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"from\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"data\":\"0x7b84daec00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280000000000000000000000009fd15feb6f86d2da6a3ac17372debd1db4e02e93\",\"to\":\"0xbda1f897e851c7ef22cd490d2cf2dace4645a904\"},\"latest\"]}",
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "omit"
  });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

The error I am getting is:

```
"Exception: Request failed for https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"error":{"details":"Unrecognized JSONRPC command","code":-32005},"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"
```

P.S.: I have "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"] in my appscript.json.

Comment: for starters, try changing `"body"` to `"payload"` in the options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script POST request UrlFetchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367076/google-apps-script-post-request-urlfetchapp)

Comment: That was it? Yes it was. Hours of life wasted... Thank you!

Comment: @Kibou Please post an answer so that the question doesn't stay unanswered. Thanks

Comment: I have a follow-up question. How to convert that query into one that I can use in Google Script?

`https://terraswap-graph.terra.dev/graphql?query=%7B%0A%20%20pair%28pairAddress%3A%20%22terra1774f8rwx76k7ruy0gqnzq25wh7lmd72eg6eqp5%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20latestToken1Price%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A`