# Use Firebase for Google Apps Script Link Shortening

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883286

I'm told I have to use Firebase to shorten a long url for a google script. I don't know what Firebase is or how to use it.

The other person provided a script, but I'm not sure how I can get an API key to use this.